# How to get images from upload folder created by multer on heroku node application in separate angular application?

Tags: angularjs, mean-stack

I am unable to get the images from heroku server. I have deployed my node application with restful APIs. I am using multer to upload files in images/upload/ folder and I want to call this image with rest API call.

And I want to access these images from specific url like 
e.g : "https://someone@herokuapp.com/client/images/uploads/images(name)"
 
Here are the some snapshots--

[image]

Comment: having the same problem. i think heroku dont allow it